# How to dynamically add components on a custom dialog?

Tags: android

Let's say I have a listView with some formulas like this:

```
((A * 2 + B * 3 + PF * 5) / 10)
```

When I click on it I would like to change the letters to `EditTexts`, so I split this `String` then, if it is a letter I should replace it by an EditText, so, what should I use to make this happen? I mean, can I have an activity loaded on a "Dialog Style" window? Or I can make this work with Simple Dialog?

I've tried this, but it gets error when adding the view(`NullPointerException`)

```
lsView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> aView, View view,
            int i, long l) {
    Dialog dialogFormula = new Dialog(NotasActivity.this); //"Parent" activity

    dialogFormula.setTitle("Title");

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.DialogLayout);
    String[] lines = materias.get(i).getFormula().split(" ");
    for (String s : lines) {
        if (s.compareTo("PARTIC") == 0) {
            EditText edtPartic = new EditText(dialogFormula.getContext));
            layout.addView(edtPartic);
        } else if (s.contains("A") && s.compareTo("A") != 0) {
        } else if (s.compareTo("B") == 0) {
        } else if (s.compareTo("C") == 0) {
        } else if (s.compareTo("D") == 0) {
        } else if (s.compareTo("E") == 0) {
        } else if (s.compareTo("F") == 0) {
        } else if (s.compareTo("G") == 0) {
        } else if (s.compareTo("H") == 0) {
        } else if (s.compareTo("I") == 0) {
        } else if (s.compareTo("PF") == 0) {
    } 
                }
    dialogFormula.setContentView(layout);
    return false;
}
});
```

dialog_formula.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:id="@+id/DialogLayout">



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMateriaDialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtFormulaDialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where is layout declared in xml?
Also, what error are you getting? Null Pointer?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line: `LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.DialogLayout);`?

Comment: I'm trying to link the layout on the XML in order to add the EditText that i'm adding by code

Comment: I'm sorry, are you trying to open (inflate) the nameless XML file you have posted, add the appropriate number of EditTexts, and then set the XML as the layout of the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you make a custom dialog class.

```
public class FormulaDialog extends Dialog {

    public FormulaDialog(Context c) {
        super(c);
        setTitle("Title");
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_formula);
    }

    public void updateLayout(String[] lines) {
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.DialogLayout);
        for (String s : lines) {
            if (s.compareTo("PARTIC") == 0) {
                EditText edtPartic = new EditText(dialogFormula.getContext));
                layout.addView(edtPartic);
            } else if (s.contains("A") && s.compareTo("A") != 0) {
            } else if (s.compareTo("B") == 0) {
            } else if (s.compareTo("C") == 0) {
            } else if (s.compareTo("D") == 0) {
            } else if (s.compareTo("E") == 0) {
            } else if (s.compareTo("F") == 0) {
            } else if (s.compareTo("G") == 0) {
            } else if (s.compareTo("H") == 0) {
            } else if (s.compareTo("I") == 0) {
            } else if (s.compareTo("PF") == 0) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your Activity all you have to run is

```
String[] lines = materias.get(i).getFormula().split(" ");
FormulaDialog mFormulaDialog = new FormulaDialog(this);
mFormulaDialog.updateLayout(lines);
mFormulaDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

findViewById() only returns views in the XML passed to the current Activity's setContentView(), typically this is your main.xml for your first activity. Since `DialogLayout` is in a different XML, this line returns null:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.DialogLayout);
```

You want to inflate `dialog_formula.xml`, modify it, and then pass this XML to your Dialog; like this:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_formula, null, false);

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.DialogLayout);
// Add your new EditTexts here

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Title");
builder.setView(view);
dialog = builder.create();
```

To parse your formula, I have two different recommendations:

- Keep a count of user variables for each formula, rather than parse the same string over and over.
- If you must parse, test your string like this:

  ```
  if("ABCDEFGHIPF".contains(s))
      // Add EditText
  else if(s.contains("PARTIC"))
      // Do something special
  // The rest are numbers or symbols
  ```